# Hyperlink on ID in table rows read from DB

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make the event ID clickable, preferably the entire row but just the ID is fine and I need to be able to open the Event relating to the ID. I would presume there is some way to make an array that reads the EventID from each row but I could never grasp arrays. From what ive been looking through people say this is done with Ajax but I would rather not use Ajax if I can code my way out of it :P

Although from what I understand of Ajax can I do some kind of on.click that reads the ID, I really have no clue.

This is what I have for displaying the table and the hyper link:

```
  <?php 
                foreach($result as $row){  



   echo    "<tr>";

   echo '<td><a href="single.php" '. $single = $row['EventID'] . '>'.$row['EventID'].'</a></td>';
   echo      "<td>". $row['EmployeeNo'] ."</td>";
   echo      "<td>". $row['EventServices'] ."</td>";
   echo      "<td>". $row['EventCategory'] ."</td>";
   echo      "<td>". $row['EventStatus'] ."</td>";
        "</tr>";
      } 

     ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make what you have send a `$_GET` request, change your link.

```
<?php 
    foreach($result as $row){ ?>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="single.php?EventID=<?php echo $row['EventID']; ?>"><?php echo $row['EventID']; ?></a></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['EmployeeNo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['EventServices']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['EventCategory']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['EventStatus']; ?></td>
    </tr><?php
      } ?>
```

On your `single.php` page, if you `print_r($_GET)` after clicking the link on this page, you should print out `array('EventID'=>123)`.

I presume you know this, but just incase, to access the array value on the `single.php` page:

**single.php**

```
<?php
// To echo the value
echo strip_tags($_GET['EventID']);
// To print array
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

Comment: How do I call the $_GET request, or save to data from the get to a variable

Comment: See full example above. On the `single.php` page, you can assign the EventID like so: `$variable = strip_tags($_GET['EventID']);` I don't know what you want to do with it after the fact though. That is not clear. I am just demonstrating how to create a clickable link on one page and display it on another. After that you can take that a use it how you need to.

Comment: Did not realise it was so simple :P